# How do I chain multiple conditional promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

In my code I have conditional tasks, which all return a promise. I need the tasks to run in sequence.

My current implementation looks something like this:

```
var chain = [];

if (/* some condition for task A */) {
    chain.push(function(doContinue){
        taskA().then(doContinue);
    });
}

if (/* some condition for task B */) {
    chain.push(function(doContinue){
        taskB().then(doContinue);
    });
}

if (/* some condition for task C */) {
    chain.push(function(doContinue){
        taskC().then(doContinue);
    });
}

var processChain = function () {
    if (chain.length) {
        chain.shift()(processChain);
    } else {
        console.log("all tasks done");
    }
};

processChain();
```

This works fine, but initially I was looking for a way to create the chain using only Promises and chaining all functions using `.then`, but I wasn't able to get a working solution.

If there's a cleaner way using only Promises and chains of `then` calls, then I'd love to see an example.

Comment: Do you need the conditions to be evaluated asynchronously (i.e. after the previous promise step) or just synchronously?

Comment: @Bergi The conditions can be evaluated at the start and don't rely on the results generated by promises.

Comment: Then raina77ows solution is perfect for you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
var promiseChain = Promise.resolve();
if (shouldAddA) promiseChain = promiseChain.then(taskA);
if (shouldAddB) promiseChain = promiseChain.then(taskB);
if (shouldAddC) promiseChain = promiseChain.then(taskC);
return promiseChain;
```

Another one:

```
return Promise.resolve()
  .then(shouldAddA && taskA)
  .then(shouldAddB && taskB)
  .then(shouldAddC && taskC);
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that these two approaches are not completely equivalent. 
In Approach 1, each `.then()` is either chained of not chained. 
In Approach 2, each `.then()` is chained unconditionally, and either has or does not have a success handler. 
Every chained `.then()`, even without a handler, introduces downstream delay, therefore Approach 2 will introduce additional downstream delay for each failed test, compared to Approach 1.

Comment: In many, maybe most circumstances, the difference won't matter. 
The order of magnitude of the delay (on a 1.4 GHz Netbook using native Promises in jsFiddle under Opera 41.0), is about 1 second per 10000 `.then(null)`. 
The most likely scenario where a difference might be manifest is where some other promise was raced against the constructed chain; Approach 2 would have an increased chance of losing the race compared with Approach 1.

Comment: You're God! It really works! And is SO clean! :D why is the promiseChain returned not called? How is it actually initiated?

Comment: Because promises are never 'called'. One needs to create a chain of actions and react on its resolution - either successful or not. `promiseChain` stores an object that encapsulates this chain.

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks for the explanation. I wouldn't fully agree that you don't 'call' promises, as something must initally trigger execution of this chain of events (and it's apparently stating the name of the encapsulating object), otherwise it would execute each time you add new action, but I get your point. Anyway your solution is great, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new `async`/`await` syntax

```
async function foo () {
  let a = await taskA()
  if (a > 5) return a // some condition, value

  let b = await taskB()
  if (b === 0) return [a,b] // some condition, value

  let c = await taskC()
  if (c < 0) return "c is negative" // some condition, value

  return "otherwise this"
}

foo().then(result => console.log(result))
```

What's nice about this is – aside from the code being very flat and readable (imo) – values `a`, `b`, and `c` are all available in the same scope. This means your conditions and return values can depend on any combination of your tasks' promised values.

Comment: Your example, while helpful, is a bit of a different scenario than the original question. The question was how to conditionalize (or skip over) an async operation, but yours will always run in order from top to bottom, conditionalizing the second or third operation.

Comment: @BeniRose I'm  unsure what you mean – eg when `a > 5`, neither `taskB` nor `taskC` will be executed – those async operations will effectively be *skipped over* – based on a conditional. If `taskA` is meant to be controlled by some external condition, that's fine too. This answer demonstrates `async`/`await` essentially allows you to blur the lines between synchronous and asynchronous code.

Comment: ie this question of *"chaining multiple conditional promises"* disappears when you understand how `async`/`await` works – the asker's mind is free from terms like *"chain"* and even *"promise"*; the question becomes *"how to sequence multiple conditions?"*; which has a trivial answer: `if ...`/`else if ...`/`else ...`

Comment: `async`/`await` demonstrate how language keywords can take abstractions like `Promise` to the next level. The programmer isn't concerned with *"resolving"* or *"rejecting"* or `.then` and `.catch`; the entire Promise API can be forgotten. The programmer can write ordinary programs with high-level keywords around functions and function calls that involve asynchrony. Missing this critical distinction is looking at the power of abstraction with blind eyes.